# Using the results of a Class Microsoft Access Query

Tags: ms-access

How do I Initialise and use the properties/methods of a My Class in each row of my Query.

In this example I have a Class with the method **Add** and the property **Result**

My Table has two columns, with two values (v1 and v2)

I want to create a query which uses my Class to add the two numbers together, so the resulting query will have three columns:

```
v1, v2, Class.Result
```

Somewhere/how I need to call

```
New Class()
Class.Add(v1,v2)
```

Comment: Why are you doing this? Queries add columns very well. Is this a school exercise?

Comment: No, it's not a school exercise :-)  I have a Class which I am using in a Form.  The Class has 32 properties which are generated based on 4 fields in the Form.  When you fill out the 4 values on the form and click the "DoIt" button, the Class is "Initialized" and then the 32 properties are extracted and put into txtBoxes.  Now what I would like to be able to do is reuse that class in a query so as to have a query with 32+4 columns.  I realise that I could take all the logic out of the class and turn it into functions,  but I really don't want to have to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call a function in the query. Create a function that takes the two values as input parameters and returns the value you want. The function will be evaluated for each record meaning performance will suck on large recordsets, but it will do what you need.

Comment: This would require creating the class 32 times for every record of the query?  Is there no way to create the class once per row and access the class 32 times?